# Isolating $t$ in $-8\sin(t)\cos(t)+3(\sin(t)^2 - \cos(t)^2)=0$

Tags: trigonometry

$$-8\sin(t)\cos(t)+3(\sin(t)^2 - \cos(t)^2)=0$$

I was solving a problem and arrived at this equation. Is there a way to solve this for $t\in (0,2\pi)$ without a computer, and if so, how would you go about doing it? From here I just booted up maple, but I would love to know what the approach is by hand.

Comment: $2\sin t \cos t=\sin (2t), 1+\cos (2t) =2\cos^{2}(t)$ and $1-\cos (2t) =2\sin ^{2}(t)$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Avoid using $*$ to denote multiplication. That's a common practice in programming, not in Mathematics.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Thanks! I'll use that next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by $\cos^2 t$ to get $3\tan^2 t-8\tan t-3=0$. Solve the quadratic to get $\tan t = 3, -\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: By far the best solution ! [How could I miss that !?]

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely the simplest solution!

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to solve:

$$3\left(\sin^2\left(x\right)-\cos^2\left(x\right)\right)-8\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(x\right)=0\tag1$$

The left hand side factors into a product with three terms:

$$-\left(3\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)\left(\cos\left(x\right)+3\sin\left(x\right)\right)=0\tag2$$

Multiply both sides by $-1$:

$$\left(3\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)\left(\cos\left(x\right)+3\sin\left(x\right)\right)=0\tag3$$

Split into two equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
3\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)=0\\
\\
\cos\left(x\right)+3\sin\left(x\right)=0
\end{cases}\space\Longleftrightarrow\space\begin{cases}
\cot\left(x\right)=\frac{1}{3}\\
\\
\tan\left(x\right)=-\frac{1}{3}
\end{cases}\tag4
$$

> I'll let you finish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't believe I missed that factorization. Really well illustrated

Comment: @GabrielRuge You're welcome! I am glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You have\begin{align}-8\sin(t)\cos(t)+3\bigl(\sin^2(t)-\cos^2(t)\bigr)=0&\iff8\sin(t)\cos(t)+3\bigl(\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)\bigr)=0\\&\iff4\sin(2t)+3\cos(2t)=0\\&\iff\frac45\sin(2t)+\frac35\cos(2t)=0\\&\iff\cos(\alpha)\sin(2t)+\sin(\alpha)\cos(2t)=0,\end{align}where $\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac45\right)$. But$$\cos(\alpha)\sin(2t)+\sin(\alpha)\cos(2t)=\cos(\alpha+2t).$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Why not just $\tan(2t)=-\dfrac34$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust That was my first thought, but I think that finding the solutions of $\cos(\alpha+2t)=0$ is slightly simpler than finding the solutions of $\tan(2t)=-\frac34$. But it's a matter of taste, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Using the double angle formula, the equation write
$$4 \sin (2 t)+3 \cos (2 t)=0$$
Let $t=\tan^{-1}(x)$
$$\frac {3 x^2-8 x-3 } {1+x^2}=0\implies \frac {(x-3) (3 x+1)} {1+x^2}=0$$

Comment: Thanks! This was my introduction to the double angle formula